# Angular directive to change button state before and after ajax

Tags: ajax, angularjs

My application contains a form with a save button. When the form is submitted, a function `save()` is called, which executes an ajax request to submit the form.  How can I create a directive to change the text of the button to "Loading...", while the ajax request is executing, and then set it back to "Save" when the request completes?

Is a directive the right way to approach this, or am I thinking about it the wrong way?

Comment: Hi there!, may I have some feedback please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I usually do (ok, is Jade but you get the idea right?):

```
button(type="submit", ng-if="!saving") Save
button(type="button", ng-if="saving") Saving...
```

So, in your controller just set `$scope.saving = true;` before the ajax call and change it on finally:

```
$scope.saving = true;
$http
...
.finally(function () { $scope.saving = false; });
```

And if you want to give more info, like showing something on success (`.then`) or on fail (`.catch`) then you can use `ngSwitch` too.

Dunno but crafting a directive for this seems overkilling and not so flexible as this solution.